# Using Puma with Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, puma

My configuration:

```
Rails 5.2.3
Ruby 2.6.3
rbenv
puma
capistrano
nginx
Ubuntu 18.04
```

I've been reading up on how to get all this setup and configured for deployment, but I don't seem to be able to find one place, that's got a clear and complete guide.

One of the things that confuse me the most is Puma. Some of the guides, do not mention anything about configuring Puma on the server, and all the instructions, reference the Puma Gem. A couple of other guides, discuss setting up and configuring Puma on the server, and modifications in the /etc/init folder.

Do I need to setup and configure Puma on the server, separately, before I can start using it for my Rails application?

Answer (score 2):

No you do not need to set up and configure Puma on the server. Puma is a gem. So if you list it in your application's Gemfile, when you run `bundle install` for your Rails application, Puma will be installed automatically.

Any configuration for puma should go in your application, under `config/puma.rb`.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Hm, taking a closer look at your question, I don't think I've answered it. I just stumbled across https://github.com/seuros/capistrano-puma and suspect your question might be more related to that

Comment: I've seen the gem documentation, and it does not refer to server-only setup, prior to starting Rails, but some of the guides refer to a server setup. So much misinformation out there, but I could not find a single complete, and useful Rails 5.2 + Puma + Capistrano + Rbenv + Puma + Nginx

Comment: What guides have you seen that refer to a server setup? I can take a look at them.

Comment: Here's one: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-puma-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04 Here's another: https://coderwall.com/p/ttrhow/deploying-rails-app-using-nginx-puma-and-capistrano-3 If you have done a successful deployment for the configuration I listed, and you've used a particular guide, I would appreciate a link

Comment: One of the issues with those articles, is that they're out of date. The DigitalOcean one is geared towards DO customers since DO provides server hosting similar to AWS EC2. The Coderwall one is nicer because it shows various steps related to Capistrano, as well as Puma and Nginx. I can't comment on some of the Ubuntu-specific stuff, since we (the company I work for) use AWS with AL2 (Amazon Linux 2).

Answer (score 2):

When running Rails locally, just use `config/puma.rb` for your Puma config, and run Puma similar to the following:

```sh
RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT=1 bin/pumactl -F config/puma.rb start
```

The above will run Puma in the foreground. I personally use Overmind in development to run Puma, Webpacker, Sidekiq, and sometimes ngrok. That means I only need one iTerm tab for all of those.

To get `bin/pumactl`, run `bin/bundle binstubs puma`.

You could also run Puma using `bin/rails server`, but Puma recommends not doing that because not all of Puma's configuration options are available through that method.

A sample Puma config (based on what the `capistrano3-puma` gem produces [https://github.com/seuros/capistrano-puma/blob/v4.0.0/lib/capistrano/templates/puma.rb.erb]):

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true
# config/puma.rb

require 'dotenv/load' # load a .env file for environment variables; gem 'dotenv-rails'
require 'nenv' # nicer ENV handling; gem 'nenv'

directory(File.expand_path('..', __dir__))
rackup(File.expand_path('../config.ru', __dir__))
environment(Nenv.rack_env || Nenv.rails_env || 'development')
# or without nenv
#environment(ENV['RACK_ENV'] || ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'development')

threads(0, (Nenv.max_threads || 16).to_i)
# or without nenv
#threads(0, (ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 16).to_i)

port((Nenv.port || 3_000).to_i)
# or without nenv
#port((ENV['PORT'] || 3_000).to_i)

workers 0

restart_command 'bundle exec puma'

prune_bundler

on_restart do
  puts('Refreshing Gemfile...') # rubocop:disable Rails/Output
  Nenv.bundle_gemfile = File.expand_path('../Gemfile', __dir__)
  # or without nenv
  #ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] = File.expand_path('../Gemfile', __dir__)
end
```

For handling Puma using Capistrano, I recommend the `capistrano3-puma` gem (https://github.com/seuros/capistrano-puma). This gem has various tasks, one of which is `puma:config` which will create a `puma.rb` file in the `shared` directory. You would then add `puma.rb` to the `:linked_files` Capistrano config option:

```rb
# config/deploy.rb
append(:linked_files, 'puma.rb')
```

As for setting up a server (one you deploy to), you want to install Nginx and set that up to serve your Rails app. Again, the `capistrano3-puma` gem can come in handy for this, as it includes an Nginx plugin which provides a task to upload a config to your server. If you don't want to use that plugin, then I'd at least recommend looking at the template (https://github.com/seuros/capistrano-puma/blob/v4.0.0/lib/capistrano/templates/nginx_conf.erb) for that config, and then adapting it to your needs.

As @matt-v-from-toronto mentioned, Puma is installed as part of your app, and not separately on the server. Doing a `bin/bundle install`, or similar, will install Puma along with all of your other gems listed in your `Gemfile`.